# Real vncviewer from command-line won't use saved passwords

Tags: command-line, password, vnc

I have Real vncviewer setup and it has some regular connections I use that have saved passwords (I can connect automatically by starting up the vncviewer GUI and opening the saved connection).

But if I try to connect to the vnc with the commandline, either by:

```
% vncviewer <hostname>
% vncviewer .vnc/ViewerStore/<path-of-saved-vnc>.vnc
```

Then it still asks for the user/password.

I can specify the --UserName=, but I have no way to specify the password (and would rather use the saved password in the .vnc/identities.

Is this possible with Real VNCViewer?

I don't really want to switch to TightVncViewer because it requires changing my VNC servers and conflicts with the Real VNCViewer installation I have.